# Understanding Assembly Hello World

Tags: assembly, x86

I have this Hello World example that is part of a course I'm using for learning assembly:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
push offset aHelloWorld; "Hello world\n"
call ds:__imp__printf
add esp, 4
mov eax, 1234h
pop ebp
retn
```

This code was generated by Windows Visual C++ 2005 with buffer overflow protection turned off and disassembled with IDA Pro 4.9 Free Version.

I'm trying to understand what each line does.

the first line is `push ebp`.

I know `ebp` stands for **base pointer**. What is its function?

I see that in the second line the value in `esp` is moved into `ebp` and searching online I see that there first 2 instructions are very common at the beginning of an assembly program.

Though are `ebp` and `esp` empty at the beginning? I'm new to assembly. Is `ebp` used for stack frames, so when we have a function in our code and is it optional for a simple program?

Then `push offset aHelloWorld; "Hello world\n"`

The part after `;` is a comment so it doesn't get executed right? The first part instead adds the address containing the string Hello World to the stack, right? But where is the string declared? I'm not sure I understand.

Then `call ds:__imp__printf`

it seems it's a call to a function, anyway `printf` is a builtin function right?
And does `ds` stand for **data segment register**? Is it used because we are trying to access a memory operand that isn't on the stack?

then `add esp, 4`

do we add 4 bytes to esp? Why?

then `move eax, 1234h`  what is 1234h here?

then `pop ebx`..it was pushed at the beginning. is it necessary to pop it at the end?

then `retn` ( i knew about `ret` for returning a value after calling a function). I read that the n in retn refers to the number of pushed arguments by the caller. It isn't very clear for me.
Can you help me to understand?

Comment: I wonder why do you want to develop exploits? The current SW is already quite faulty as is, and working many times just by pure accident. Nowadays it's often more effort to not bring it down by regular usage, than to crash it by exploit. Too scared to do some real coding, so you want to stay with the easy side?

Comment: I work in information security and I want to learn exploit development as well. Simple. Anyway this is just an hello word example that does no harm. Can you help me to understand the code well?

Comment: I'm trying, but you have so many questions, and you are so green to this, that it would probably make more sense to return to some tutorials and documents, also some computer architecture books, etc... I'm writing down some partial answer, but don't expect much.

Comment: BTW, this "simple no-harm hello world" looks like it is loading the `printf` from dynamic library. So if you would somehow (by some attack) inject malicious dll during execution of this, with patched malicious `printf` version, it may do lot of harm (at least in the context under which you run the hello world, unless that malicious code uses some other bug to escalate it's privileges and escape the current context, etc...). ... so much for the "no harm" ... :D

Comment: @Ped7g yeah, I understand the logic :) Just not ready yet to do something like that. Maybe after a few thousand pages of books..I really need to find a good book about assembly and study. Assembly is also taught at some university courses. Studying on your own can be hard.

Comment: I learned assembly as 12 y.o. child. Took me only about 15 years.

Comment: there are even different syntaxes, different assemblers, differences between an operating system and another..differences from an architecture and another (although now I'm focusing on x86), so getting lost is easy and it requires many prerequisites..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm trying to understand what each line does.

That would fall under the general category of learning assembly language. There are entire books written about this topic; some of them are probably even pretty good. You should purchase one. To ensure that you get maximum bang for your buck, be sure to select one that focuses on the architecture and operating system you're interested in. x86 assembly language is, of course, always the same, but the programming model differs enough between Windows and Linux that the differences would be confusing to a beginner.

If you're too cheap to buy a book, *at least* read Matt Pietrek's classic series of articles, *"Just Enough Assembly To Get By"*, from the Microsoft System Journal. [Start here](https://www.microsoft.com/msj/0298/hood0298.aspx), and proceed to the [follow-up](https://www.microsoft.com/msj/0698/hood0698.aspx).

> The first line is `push ebp`. I know `ebp` stands for **base pointer**. What is its function?
>
> I see that in the second line the value in `esp` is moved into `ebp` and searching online I see that there first 2 instructions are very common at the beginning of an assembly program.
>
> I'm new to assembly. Is `ebp` used for stack frames, so when we have a function in our code and is it optional for a simple program?

To understand this first line in isolation, you just need to know what a `PUSH` instruction does. It pushes the operand (in this case, a register) onto the top of the stack. `EBP` is the register that almost always contains the stack base pointer.

That doesn't tell you much about the *purpose* of this code, though. This line and the next one are part of the [standard function prologue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prologue). Matt talks about that near the beginning of his very first article, in the "Procedure Entry and Exit" section. First, the stack base pointer from `EBP` is saved by `PUSH`ing it onto the stack. Then, the second instruction copies the value of `ESP` into the `EBP` register. This makes interacting with the stack throughout the function easier. Generally, the prologue section would end with an instruction that reserved an arbitrary amount of space on the stack for temporary variables (*e.g.*, `sub esp, 8` to reserve 8 bytes on the stack). This function doesn't need any.

Yes, this prologue code is optional. If you don't need any stack space and/or you use `EBP`-relative addressing, then you don't need the standard prologue. [Optimizing compilers often omit it](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2007/03/12/fpo/) when possible.

> Though are `ebp` and `esp` empty at the beginning?

No, of course they are not empty. If they were empty, the code wouldn't bother to save the value of `EBP` or use the value of `ESP`.

In fact, *no* registers are empty at the beginning of a function. They contain either the values that the function's prototype (in conjunction with its calling convention) says that they do, they contain values that you must preserve (that is, they must still have the same values when your function returns control that they did when your function was first called; these are called *caller-save* registers, and which ones they are differ depending on the calling convention), or they contain what you can assume to be garbage values (these are the *callee-save* registers and you are free to clobber them in the callee function's code).

> Then `push offset aHelloWorld; "Hello world\n"`
>
> The part after `;` is a comment so it doesn't get executed right? The first part instead adds the address containing the string Hello World to the stack, right? But where is the string declared? I'm not sure I understand.

`aHelloWorld` is a piece of global data declared in the executable image. It was put there at link time, probably because the original code used a string literal. This instruction `PUSH`es the `offset` of that global data (that is, its address) onto the stack.

Yes, the part after the semicolon is a comma. The disassembler is adding this comment as a favor to you. It has looked up the value of `aHelloWorld`, determined that it contains the string `Hello world\n`, and placed that definition in-line, saving you from having to look up the data's value yourself.

> Then `call ds:__imp__printf`
>
> it seems it's a call to a function, anyway `printf` is a builtin function right?

Yes, `CALL` always calls a function. In this case, it is calling the `printf` function. Is it a "built-in" function? That depends on your definition. From the perspective of assembly language, no: no function is built-in. `printf` is a function provided by the C standard library. When the original code was compiled and linked, it was *also* linked with the C run-time library, which provides the C standard library functions, including `printf`. Since this is MSVC, the `__imp__` prefix is a big hint that the function being called is part of either the standard library or the Windows API. These are implicitly linked functions.

Looking up the `printf` function shows that it takes a variable number of arguments. In the most common x86-32 calling conventions, these arguments are passed on the stack. So that explains why the previous instruction `PUSH`ed the address of string data onto the stack: it's passing that address to the `printf` function so that string can be printed to the standard output. It could have passed additional arguments to `printf`, but it didn't, because it didn't need to: it just needed one to print a literal string.

> And does `ds` stand for **data segment register**? Is it used because we are trying to access a memory operand that isn't on the stack?

Yes, DS is the data segment. Your disassembler is just being verbose here. In Windows, x86-32 uses a [flat memory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_memory_model), so you can basically ignore the [segment registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation) entirely and still understand everything that is going on perfectly well.

> then `add esp, 4`
>
> do we add 4 bytes to esp? Why?

Yes, this adds 4 bytes to the `ESP` register. Why? To clean up the stack. Recall that before `CALL`ing the `printf` function, you `PUSH`ed a 4-byte value (the offset of the string data in the executable image) on the stack. The `printf` function is *variadic* (takes a variable number of arguments), so the caller is always responsible for cleaning up the stack after calling it.

Here, you can think of adding 4 to `ESP` is equivalent to popping the stack with a `POP` instruction. On x86, the stack always grows downwards, so adding is equivalent to popping (and the inverse of pushing).

> then `move eax, 1234h`  what is 1234h here?

This instruction `MOV`es the constant value `0x1234` (the `h` means hexadecimal) into the `EAX` register.

Why? Well, I can guess. In all of the x86 calling conventions, the `EAX` register contains a function's return value. So it is very likely that the function's original code ended with `return 0x1234;`.

> then `pop ebx`..it was pushed at the beginning. is it necessary to pop it at the end?

Actually, it pops `EBP`, which is what was actually pushed at the beginning of the function.

And yes. Everything that you `PUSH` onto the stack has to be `POP`ed off the stack. (Or equivalent, as we saw earlier with `ADD`ing to `ESP`.) You have to clean up the stack. This is the function *epilogue* that corresponds to the *prologue* that we saw at the beginning. Refer back to Matt's article, where it talks about "Procedure Entry and Exit".

> then `retn` ( i knew about `ret` for returning a value after calling a function). I read that the n in retn refers to the number of pushed arguments by the caller.

This is just an idiosyncracy of your disassembler again. IDA Pro uses the `retn` mnemonic. This actually means a *near* return, but since x86-32 uses a flat (non-segmented) memory model, the near vs. far distinction is not relevant. You can think of `retn` as simply being equivalent to `ret`.

Note that this is distinct from the `ret` instruction that takes *an argument*, which is what you're thinking of. It doesn't "return" its argument, though. The function returns its result in the `EAX` register. Rather, `ret n` (where `n` is 16-byte immediate value) returns and pops the specified number of bytes off the stack. This is used only for certain calling conventions (most commonly `__stdcall`) where the callee is responsible for cleaning up the stack.

See links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) for more information on calling conventions.

> It isn't very clear for me.
> Can you help me to understand?

Did I mention you should get a book that teaches assembly language programming?

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is clear and I'm surely willing to learn assembly. I don't mind investing time and money in it. I already have a book, I just started learning and I started a video course but maybe its pace is too fast and I need to learn more basics first.

Comment: I think the mistake many people make in trying to learn assembly is failing to learn C (or C++) first. You really need to understand calling conventions, linking, and the basics of programming for your operating system first. Without that, you're just memorizing the assembly operand mnemonics and a description of their function, which only gives you half of the picture. A sufficiently smart disassembler could do that (add generic annotations to each instruction). A human is needed to understand *why* the code does what it does, especially if you're reverse-engineering.

Comment: @Fabio maybe check also "assembly" documentation here at SO, with the general introduction/machine code/stack/registers.. it's very limited at the moment, so you will be quickly done trough it. With some luck it may fill up to the other info (or make you even more confused). And that "empty at the beginning" is you confusing C concepts (parameter passed by copy of value) with the registers. Registers are fixed pieces of silicone chip, having some values in their bits since you connected CPU to the valid current. They can't be empty, those bits have some value all the time and it's global.

Comment: @Ped7g Thank you for the further clarification and for suggesting to take a look at assembly documentation on SO. I'll do that right now.

Comment: @CodyGray you are right. I really need to understand "why", so I need to learn more about the basics.

Comment: Isn't `call ds:__imp__printf` an indirect call via a function pointer (presumably because of dynamic linking)?  If I'm understanding MASM syntax correctly, the `ds:` is *not* just disassembler verbosity, and is the difference between loading a pointer from `[__imp__printf]` vs. jumping to that address.

Comment: `the near vs. far distinction is not relevant`.  More accurate to say "there's no use for far pointers or far calls/returns".  `retf` would pop a CS:EIP from the stack, thus crashing your program when CS indexes a different segment descriptor.  (Or if you get very lucky, CS stays the same but you return with the wrong ESP value).  I agree it's not necessary or useful to make near returns explicit, though.  I'm impressed that you wrote an answer this long.  I thought there'd already be a duplicate somewhere of most of this.

Comment: The answer turned out to be longer than I had intended. These things happen. As far as `call ds:__imp__printf`, yes, it's an indirect call. Specifically, [an indirect call through the Import Address Table](http://web.archive.org/web/20100325072155/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx) (see "Importing Functions"), which is what the `__imp__` prefix is all about. So, technically the `ds:` there is relevant, but all disassemblers I've used either do not display it, or have a "verbose" option to enable its explicit display. You aren't going to call through a different segment.

Comment: Maybe I'm too dismissive of segmentation here? I was trying to keep the answer simple, and honestly I don't have a very good grasp of how segmentation works myself. Very much before my time. @peter

Comment: @CodyGray: It's not about what segment is used, it's that `call __imp__printf` would assemble to a direct call opcode (`E8 rel32`), and would thus try to run the function-pointer *as code*.  In NASM syntax, it's the difference between `call [__imp__printf]` and `call __imp__printf`.  I've read that MASM ignores square brackets in some contexts, so I think the `ds:` is actually required for it to assemble to an indirect call (with no segment override).  Or does MASM magically know that `__imp__printf` is a function pointer, not a function?  Inferring operand size is bad enough...

Comment: @peter I have *never* seen a `ds:` prefix here in MASM, nor have I ever seen it wrapped in brackets (although that works just fine, so they are obviously ignored). The key to the magic is `EXTRN __imp__printf:PROC`. With that in place, I can literally assemble `call DWORD PTR __imp__printf` and it will do exactly what I want, assuming that I link to the appropriate CRT DLL. (`printf` is complicated, so I just tested a Windows API call.) The opcode bytes are `ff 15 00 00 00 00`. Without `EXTERN`, it'd probably interpret it as a direct call (actually, you just get an undefined symbol error).

Comment: @CodyGray: Ok, I'm not really familiar with what's normal for MASM syntax.  I mostly only see it in SO questions and people's disassembler output.  Anyway, is the  `DWORD PTR` what makes it an indirect call?  Or  does `call __imp__printf` still assemble to an indirect call because of magic based on symbol type?  (I really dislike how you can't tell how an instruction will assemble just from looking at it in isolation, in MASM.  gas and NASM/YASM don't magically look at symbol types or definitions for you.)

Comment: Yeah, it turns out that the `DWORD PTR` is exactly what does it. If you leave it off and assemble, you get a direct call (`E8 rel32`). I actually didn't know that, or at least hadn't thought about it. But it makes sense. The `PTR` is what introduces a level of indirection, exactly what you were expecting the brackets to do. I suppose one does grow far to accustomed to the tools with which he is familiar. I can pretty much tell what I'm going to get looking at MASM syntax. But a lot of that is just being familiar with the patterns, and the fact that you almost always get what you mean.